# Android : How to run callback method every loop on MediaPlayer that repeat sound

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer

How can i run callback method every loop on MediaPlayer that repeat sound? OnCompleteListener is running only once. So, i tried,

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.something);

public void play() {
  mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer paramMP) {
      mp.start();
    }
  });
  mp.start();
}
```

It has delay between each loop. So, i tried to make my own MediaPlayer to use OpenSLES(NDK) myself. But, it is already exist sample code. This is uri.

> https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio

I should add my code "loop-listener" in this C code (NDK).

```
void Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_setPlayingAssetAudioPlayer(JNIEnv* env,
        jclass clazz, jboolean isPlaying)
{
    SLresult result;

    // make sure the asset audio player was created
    if (NULL != fdPlayerPlay) {

        // set the player's state
        result = (*fdPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(fdPlayerPlay, isPlaying ?
            SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING : SL_PLAYSTATE_PAUSED);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
        (void)result;

        //#todo set loop-listener function
    }

}
```

Is there anything useful function or other way? Please help me!

Comment: https://github.com/huhx0015/HXAudioPlayer This library has a workaround for gaps between loops.

Comment: @KrupalShah thx XD. This library is useful at my project! But there's no code about that. developer hide C code. I need "setNextMediaPlayer()" source.

Comment: I found the code about gap-less. There is no C code, only Java.